# Converting Java 8 Code to Java 6: Lambda Expressions

Tags: java, java-8

I am new to `Lambda` expression and I have a Java 1.6 version. Can anyone explain how to convert the following code (Java 1.8) to Java 1.6?

```
// 1st Code
public int getEdgeCount()
{
    return adjacencyList.values()
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(Node::getEdgeCount)
            .sum();
}

// 2nd Code
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node<T> first = queue.remove();
        first.setVisited(true);
        first.edges().forEach(edge -> {
            Node<T> neighbour = edge.toNode();
            if (!neighbour.isVisited()) {
                neighbour.setParent(first);
                queue.add(neighbour);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Java 6 doesn't have lambdas. And isn't supported anymore (Feb 2013 was 22 months ago). Java 7 support ends April 2015. So what do you want us to explain exactly?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically confuses you about the lambdas? This is relatively straight forward Stream/Lambda usage, have you looked into that at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function looks through the values of `adjacencyList` (which is, probably, a map, despite confusing name), calls `.getEdgeCount` on each of them, adds up all numbers, and returns the sum.

The second function, takes nodes from the queue, loops through edges, gets `.toNode()` of every edge, and, if it has not yet been visited, sets its parent to the current node, and adds it to the queue.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open-source project that backports the stream support to Java 6/7 at https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/

> streamsupport is a backport of the Java 8 java.util.function (functional interfaces) and java.util.stream (streams) API for users of Java 6 or 7 supplemented with selected additions from java.util.concurrent which didn't exist back in Java 6.